# How can I save definitely the new location of a TableLayoutPanel after a drag and drop in a panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop

I'm trying a drag and drop for a tablelayoutpanel in a panel using winforms/c#, the drag and drop of the tablelayoutpanel works successfully but how can I save the new location of the tablelayoutpanel using a button action ? Any solution please ?

```
private void Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
     panel2.AllowDrop = true;
     tableLayoutPanel1.AllowDrop = true;
     panel2.DragEnter += panel2_DragEnter;   
     panel2.DragDrop += panel2_DragDrop;
     tableLayoutPanel1.MouseDown += tableLayoutPanel1_MouseDown;
}   

private void panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TableLayoutPanel))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

}

private void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     var tlp = (TableLayoutPanel)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TableLayoutPanel));
    tlp.Location = panel2.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    tlp.Parent = panel2;
    tlp.BringToFront();             
}
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     tableLayoutPanel1.DoDragDrop(tableLayoutPanel1, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i find a solution to my problem. the idea is to save the location of the items in the database (Location.X a,d Location.Y) then in the load page we fix the location of the dropped item with the location saved in the database.